# PowerShell - Open Excel and Unlock Certain Cells Based On Value

Tags: excel, powershell, reporting-services

I have a report that I am running via SSRS to brings down some data that I need people to give comments on. I am attempting to write a PowerShell script that will open the file and unprotect certain cells based on their value.

This is what the report looks like:[image]

The default for SSRS is that all cells are automatically protected. However, I would like to unprotect all the cells in column A (the column with the yellow text boxes) that do not have the value of "Manager Comments".

I am not really sure how to go about this. I have this so far for my script:

```
Param(
[string] $FolderPath,
[string] $FileName
)
Write-Output $FolderPath
Write-Output $FileName

$Files = Dir $FolderPath -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -eq $FileName} | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
$excl=New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
foreach ($file in $Files)
{
    $wrkb=$excl.Workbooks.Open($file, 0, $false)
    $wrkb.Worksheets("Comments").Range("A1:A100").Locked = $False
    $wrkb.Save()
    $wrkb.Close()
}
$excl.Quit()
```

But this will just unprotect all of column A. Does anyone know how to have it look at the values and only unprotect those blank values? Bonus points if it can just look for certain colors (the yellow).

And yes, I know that this is a terrible way of doing this...but I work with what I have.

---

A little progress update...I now can pull the value and cell color index in a loop, but I am not sure how to write the IF statement to lock the cell if the $Color value is equal to "36".

```
Param(
    [string] $FolderPath = "C:\Root\Data\VisualCron\Development\",
    [string] $FileName = "Combined Master Report.xlsx"
)
Write-Output $FolderPath
Write-Output $FileName

$Files = Dir $FolderPath -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -eq $FileName} | Select -ExpandProperty FullName

$SheetName = "Comments"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File, 0, $False)
    $Sheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item("Comments")

    $MaxRow = ($Sheet.UsedRange.Rows).Count

    $Row,$Column = 1,1
        for ($i = 0; $i -le $MaxRow - 1; $i++)
        {
            $Color = $Sheet.Cells.Item($Row+$i,$Column).Interior.ColorIndex
            $Value = $Sheet.Cells.Item($Row+$i,$Column).Text

                
            Write-Host ("Color Value:" + $Color + " " + $i + " " + $Value)
        }

    #$Workbook.Worksheets("Comments").Range("A3:A50").Locked = $False
    #$Workbook.Worksheets("Comments").Protect('Test',1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    $Workbook.Save()
    $Workbook.Close()
}
$excl.Quit()
```

---

Another update:

I have gotten it to work, but it is a little strange. When I first go through my loop, the color index appears to be "36", but once I change one value, the yellow index changes to "5". I am not really sure why it does that, but I wrote this script, and hopefully, it is consistent.

```
Param(
    [string] $FolderPath = "C:\Root\Data\VisualCron\Development\",
    [string] $FileName = "Combined Master Report.xlsx"
)
Write-Output $FolderPath
Write-Output $FileName

$Files = Dir $FolderPath -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -eq $FileName} | Select -ExpandProperty FullName

$SheetName = "Comments"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File, 0, $False)
    $Sheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item("Comments")

    $MaxRow = ($Sheet.UsedRange.Rows).Count

    $Row,$Column = 1,1
        for ($i = 1; $i -le $MaxRow - 1; $i++)
        {
            $Color = $Sheet.Cells.Item($Row+$i,$Column).Interior.ColorIndex
            $Value = $Sheet.Cells.Item($Row+$i,$Column).Text

            #Write-Output ($Color)
            $Range = "A" + ($Row + $i) + ":A" + ($Row + $i)
            if ($Color -eq 36 -or $Color -eq 5)
            {
                $Range = "A" + ($Row + $i) + ":A" + ($Row + $i)
                $Workbook.Worksheets("Comments").Range($Range).Locked = $False
                #Write-Host $Range
            }
        }

    $Workbook.Worksheets("Comments").Protect('Test',1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    $Workbook.Save()
    $Workbook.Close()
}
$Excel.Quit()
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why the color index would be changing?

Comment: This does not help you with your question unfortunately, but in my experience, workbooks created directly from SSRS are not protected at all. Windows may treat them has potential threats as they are downloaded from the browser but once 'unblocked' (from file properties) there is normally no issue editing anything in them.

Comment: The file itself is not protected, but all cells within the document are. My goal is to unprotect the yellow cells and then protect that particular worksheet.

Comment: I get that, I was just saying that in all my years using SSRS I've never had an excel file rendered directly from the report that has any kind of protection whatsoever.

Comment: Odd. I tested this many times and no the sheet itself is not protected, but all the cells within it are defaulted to locked, so yes I can edit them, but once I lock the sheet I cannot.